# spring mvc project layout

Tags: spring-mvc

[image][Current project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wcm7.jpg)

On my first spring mvc project, I am trying to get a better understanding of the directory structure with this project and why it is done as such

I get what goes in 'controllers' and 'views' directory, but am unsure of the others. If I look at the .java file in beans and commands, they look the same to me - no difference in annotations between the two, so why can't the 2 directories be combined into one?

What goes into services?

The mappers looks like it is for mapping with a database for an OR/M object

Not sure of resolvers directory

Is this standard way of organizing spring mvc projects?

Comment: @YevgeniyM.I have to use the tool that my company wants me to use to capture screen shot as they require the timestamp watermark.

Comment: you have my deepest sympathy. the second screenshot is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every project has its structure according to the style of organization/user. The structures abide the standards set down by the organization. So they vary from one to another. A MVC project can be broadly categoried into

1. controllers
2. services //Business Logic layer. Layer between controller and dao
3. dao // Communicates with DB
4. command or bo or vo (whatever name suits your fancy)

The above are the main three. Then there might be other folders like

1. utils //Converters, validators etc could go here or in their own package
2. resources // Place your .properties, xmls etc here

In the context of spring, any class marked with an annotation inheriting from `@Component` is a bean, so the structure that you have mentioned in the question could have been made keeping that in mind but isn't being used correctly.

The resolvers folder might host View Resolvers. This is, again, just a guess. Depends entirely on you.

You could look into maven's spring archetype and the way it organizes a spring project to get a view of how the creators of Spring organize a project.

Comment: any good link for the ' maven's spring archetype' so I could get an understanding of the structure? what goes in 'command' directory?

Comment: command hosts your objects, e.x. Person, Animal, User etc. If you're using ORM, then the objects that you persist.

Comment: Varun Achar: So then this would be the model - pojo as well as any object that is used by or/m or bound via jpa? Then i could combine command and bean directory into one?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have made 2 separate directories. Why it has been done here can only be answered by the author.

Comment: @VarunAchar where does the main application file go?

Comment: @Trajan main.java can be at the same level as the other folders. To be honest, it does not matter where you put it. It's more of a preference.

Answer (score 3):

**Spring-Hibernate project follows different project structure as per the organisation standards. A Spring MVC Project can broadly divided into following:**

```
   -java resources
        |_src
           |-com.organization.controllers  // All the controllers
                     |_ UserController
                     |_ AbcController
                     |_ -------------
                     |_ XyzController

           |-com.organization.services     // Service layer or business layer
                     |_ AbcService
                     |_ AbcServiceImpl

           |-com.organization.dao          // Data Access Layer
                     |_ AbcDao
                     |_ AbcDaoImpl

           |-com.organization.bo           // POJO or Business Object Layer
                     |_ User
                     |_ Abc

           |-resoures                      // All the resources 

           |-util                          // utilities

   -WebContent
           |-resource
                    |_css
                    |_js
                    |_image
           |-WEB-INF
                    |_lib
                    |_views
                          |_ .jsp
                    |_.xml

           |-index.jsp
```

Comment: where does the main application go?

Comment: The main application should go under the organization parent package as com.organization